# Odd behaviour when using jQuery pseudo selectors - :visible

Tags: jquery

Please can I confirm

```
$("#myElement").is(":visible");
```

is only supposed to be true if the div with id myElement is visible on the page.

I am finding that this is returning **true** regardless of whether myElement modified with:

```
$("#myElement").css("visibility","visible");
```

or

```
$("#myElement").css("visibility","hidden");
```

**Where as:**

```
$("#myElement").is(":visible")
```

returns **false** if myElement is modified with:

```
$("#myElement").css("display","none");
```

So in other words it may or may not be **false** if the element is not being displayed.

I have read and re-read the documentation. I must be missing something as I simply cannot pick out from the documentation why this is so. It does not say don't use visibility hidden nor for that matter you must use display none.

So I am not sure that I am fully understanding the reason for this and what the pseudo selector **:visible** is acting on.

Note I have also had odd behaviour when attempting to use pseudo selector **:animated**.

Could anyone please explain what is happening here in particular in reference to **:visible**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first paragraph in [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

`Visibility: hidden` still takes space on the page

Comment: +1! I've never read that in jQuerys doc. I'll have it in mind!

Comment: Sorry I was looking at http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible just didn't make that vital connection - so obvious now!